# Issue with redefinition of \maketitle in custom thesis class

Tags: titles, document-classes, center

I'm attempting to venture into some more advanced LaTeX by creating a custom thesis class for my university studies, as the existing examples are somewhat outdated and not to spec with the current style guides. As an additional aspect, I added some options that allow me to somewhat change the wording of the titlepage based on whether or not I'm using the class for a personal project or a formal dissertation.

I'm running into an issue with the redefinition of `\maketitle` where the `\end` statement of the `center` environment is cut off and bleeds into the document at large.

### `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[project]{diythesis}

\title{Construction of a Difficult, Error-Prone LaTeX Thesis Class}
\author{Not Another Author}
\degreeName{Bachelor of Science}
\majorName{Unknown Studies}
\date{August 2022}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}
    
    blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

### `diythesis.cls`:

```
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Configure basic class information and options.                              %
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{diythesis}[2022/08/16]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{project}
\newtoggle{thesis}
\newtoggle{strict}
\DeclareOption{project}{\toggletrue{project}\togglefalse{thesis}}
\DeclareOption{thesis}{\toggletrue{thesis}\togglefalse{project}}
\DeclareOption{strict}{\toggletrue{strict}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt,titlepage,twoside]{report}

\RequirePackage{fontspec,geometry,fancyhdr,afterpage,graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\RequirePackage{dcolumn,tocloft}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Configure basic page geometry and XeLaTeX font options.                     %
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\geometry{
    top    = 1.00in,
    left   = 1.25in,
    right  = 1.25in,
    bottom = 1.00in
}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newcommand{\doublespace} {
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.66}\small\normalsize
}
\newcommand{\oneandhalfspace} {
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.24}\small\normalsize
}
\newcommand{\singlespace} {
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}\small\normalsize
}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Redefine the titlepage per the graduate school formatting manual.           %
% Add additional options and commands to allow the configuration of the       %
% titlepage as a self-study project rather than a required dissertation.      %
% --------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\newlength{\fiveblanklines}\setlength{\fiveblanklines}{0.7 in}
\newlength{\tenblanklines}\setlength{\tenblanklines}{1.5 in}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\defensemonth}[1]{\renewcommand{\@defensemonth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@defensemonth}{\tt$\backslash$\string defensemonth}
\newcommand{\gradmonth}[1]{\renewcommand{\@gradmonth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@gradmonth}{\tt$\backslash$\string gradmonth}
\newcommand{\gradyear}[1]{\renewcommand{\@gradyear}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@gradyear}{\tt$\backslash$\string gradyear}
\newcommand{\chair}[1]{\renewcommand{\@chair}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@chair}{\tt$\backslash$\string chair}
\newcommand{\memberOne}[1]{\renewcommand{\@memberOne}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@memberOne}{\tt$\backslash$\string memberOne}
\newcommand{\memberTwo}[1]{\renewcommand{\@memberTwo}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@memberTwo}{\tt$\backslash$\string memberTwo}
\newcommand{\memberThree}[1]{\renewcommand{\@memberThree}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@memberThree}{\tt$\backslash$\string memberThree}
\newcommand{\memberFour}[1]{\renewcommand{\@memberFour}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@memberFour}{\tt$\backslash$\string memberFour}
\newcommand{\degreeName}[1]{\renewcommand{\@degreeName}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@degreeName}{\tt$\backslash$\string degreeName}
\newcommand{\majorName}[1]{\renewcommand{\@majorName}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@majorName}{\tt$\backslash$\string majorName}
\newcommand{\paperType}[1]{\renewcommand{\@paperType}{#1}}
\newcommand{\@paperType}{\tt$\backslash$\string paperType}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \doublespace
    \begin{center}
        {\MakeUppercase\@title} \\ by \\ \@author \\
        \vspace{\fiveblanklines}
        \iftoggle{thesis}{
            A \@paperType Presented in Partial Fulfillment \\
            of the Requirement for the Degree \\
            \@degreeName \\
        }
        \iftoggle{project}{
            An Investigatory Project Supplementing the Studies\\
            of the \@degreeName Degree in \\
            \@majorName \\
        }
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
}

\makeatother
```

The error occurs between lines 75-92 where `\maketitle` is redefined. The particular error reported by XeLaTeX is, in typical, cryptic LaTeX fashion, "`\begin{center} on input line 10 ended by \end{document}`". I'm not sure quite how to proceed given that the `\end{center}` statement can clearly be seen on line 90.

Comment: you are mis-using `\iftoggle` it is `\iftoggle{name}{yes}{no}` so `\end` is being taken as the `no` argument. So the latex message is pretty clear and accurate

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\makeat...` in a class file, also `\newcommand{\@degreeName}{\tt$\backslash$\string degreeName}` all look very odd, `\tt` should not be used in any documnent written after 1993, but you are not scoping it so this would make the rest of the document tt. You are applying `\string` to `d` whch does nothing useful. perhaps `\newcommand{\@degreeName}{\texttt{\string\degreeName}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle correcting the `\iftoggle` fixed the issue - with respect to the `\newcommand` declarations, I'm in the process of adapting an older class file, so those declarations are as found in the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mis-using `\iftoggle` it is

```
\iftoggle{name}{yes}{no}
```

so `\end` is being taken as the no argument. So the latex message is pretty clear and accurate in this case.